# Power function for mpf_class numbers in gmpxx

Tags: gmp

gmp library provides the function `void mpf_pow_ui (mpf_t rop, const mpf_t op1, unsigned long int op2)` to raise `op1` to the power `op2` (according to https://gmplib.org/manual/Float-Arithmetic#index-Powering-functions-1).

But the documentation seems to say nothing about it in the c++ interface. I've tried with names such as `pow`, `pow_iu`, `power` but none of them are defined.

Is there the way to raise a float to an exponent (either float or integer) using gmpxx?

Comment: As shown at the bottom of https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General , you can use get_mpf_t to get access to the underlying mpf_t and call whatever C function you want, like mpf_pow_ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gmpxx.h` contains interfaces to some mathematical operations like `sqrt` (see line 3341)

```
__GMP_DEFINE_UNARY_FUNCTION_1(mpf_t, sqrt, __gmp_sqrt_function)
```

where the caps-named macro depends on a general evaluation class template named `__gmp_expr<T, U>`, which in turn allows for the `eval` of expressions with mixed native and arbitray-precision types, and that's what makes the C++ GMP interface much easier to use.

But there's no such definition for `pow`. As Marc Glisse pointed out, you must convert your C++ objects to the C types using the `mpf_class::get_mpf_t` function.

The following is an example code. Name it, say, `test.cpp`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    mpf_class a = 12.3;
    unsigned long int b = 123UL;
    mpf_t c;
    mpf_set_default_prec(100000);
    mpf_init(c);
    mpf_pow_ui(c, a.get_mpf_t(), b);
    gmp_printf("c = %.50Ff\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

And compile with

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lgmpxx -lgmp
```

Which produces the output:

`114374367934618002778643226182707594198913258409535335775583252201365538178632825702225459029661601216944929436371688246107986574246790.32099077871758646985223686110515186972735931183764`

Unfortunately, even when increasing mpf precision, I can't make this agree further than 14 digits with the answer from [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12.3%5E123):

`114374367934617190099880295228066276746218078451850229775887975052369504785666896446606568365201542169649974727730628842345343196581134.89591994282087444983721209947664895835902379607854`

Note that if you want to raise an arbitrary-precision float to an arbitrary-precision float you'll need to use the function `mpfr_pow` from the [MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/) library, which by the way is [recommended](https://gmplib.org/manual/Floating_002dpoint-Functions) library to handle arbitrary-precision float:

> New projects should consider using the GMP extension library MPFR
> (http://mpfr.org) instead. MPFR provides well-defined precision and
> accurate rounding, and thereby naturally extends IEEE P754.

**EDIT**: Due to the discrepancy between GMP and WolframAlpha (which, by the way, uses GMP internally) I've posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670338/gnu-mp-low-precision-while-using-mpf-pow-function).

**EDIT2**: As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670338/gnu-mp-low-precision-while-using-mpf-pow-function#comment124931569_70670338) and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670338/gnu-mp-low-precision-while-using-mpf-pow-function#comment124931866_70670338) comments, the discrepancy is expected, since when using the `mpf_pow_ui` function the compiler converts `12.3` into a `double`, which is not exactly representable in binary, while Mathematica uses arbitrary precision for that value, so its more accurate in this particular case.

**EDIT3**: GMP can actually match the result from WolframAlpha, as explained by John Bollinger in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70670338/gnu-mp-low-precision-while-using-mpf-pow-function).

The issue with my original code is in using the `mpf_set_d` function to set the value `12.3`, because it converts to `double` and thus looses precision. John modified the code to use the `mpf_set_str` function instead, which, converted to C++, becomes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    mpf_class a("12.3",2000);
    unsigned long int b = 123UL;
    mpf_t c;
    mpf_set_default_prec(2000);
    mpf_init(c);
    mpf_pow_ui(c, a.get_mpf_t(), b);
    gmp_printf("c = %.50Ff\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

And this outputs the fully correct answer (with last digit rounded to '5' since that digit was a '4' followed by '9'):

`114374367934617190099880295228066276746218078451850229775887975052369504785666896446606568365201542169649974727730628842345343196581134.89591994282087444983721209947664895835902379607855`